# How to write a horizontal partial derivative rather than vertical form in text?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I want to write below:

(How can I write horizontally, rather than vertically)?

[image]

My MWE:

```
The partial derivative $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x_1}$ is car
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `$\partial J/\partial x_1$`.

Comment: Thanks! It works

Answer (score 3):

I will use `derivative` or `diffcoeff` package that use a short syntax as alternative to the correct comment of the very nice user @Schrödinger's cat :

*In display mode:*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\[\diffp{J}{x_1}\] % with the package diffcoeff
%\[\pdv{J}{x_1}\] % with the package derivative
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Inline math-mode: with diffcoeff package*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
$\diffp J/x_1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Addendum by comment of the user @Simon:

*Inline math-mode: with derivative package*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
$\pdv{J}/{x_1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: inline math-mode with the derivative package: `\pdv{J}/{x_1}`